How to set the last image added in order instead of the first one
I would like the last image added for the post to be displayed as a preview, not the first one. Currently it is set to 0, how can I determine the last one regardless of whether the post has 3, 4 or maybe 6 images added.
{if $cart_item['post']['photos_num'] > 0}
    <img src="{$system['system_uploads']}/{$cart_item['post']['photos'][0] ['source']}" class="w-100 h-100">
{else}
    <img src="$system['system_url']}/content/themes/{$system['theme']}/images/blank_product.png" class="w-100 h-100">
{/if}

Basically, how can I do this?

So replace [0] with [count($cart_item['post']['photos'])-1]. What's the problem?

Does this answer your question? How to get the last element of an array without deleting it?

Are you sure this problem is in any way related to [tag:post]?

You'll be looking to perform a length check on the variable 'photos_num' which will indicate the last position on the list assuming that the 'photos_num' variable represents the number of photos in the list. You can do this with the following code:
{assign var="last_position" value=$cart_item['post']['photos_num'] - 1}

{if $cart_item['post']['photos_num'] > 0}

    <img src="{$system['system_uploads']}/{$cart_item['post']['photos'][$last_position]['source']}" class="w-100 h-100">

{else}
    <img src="{$system['system_url']}/content/themes/{$system['theme']}/images/blank_product.png" class="w-100 h-100">
{/if}

